# Share to snapchat like facebook and twitter?

Tags: ios, swift, snapchat

Is there any way to share to Snapchat like we do in facebook share and twitter share?

**Example code for Facebook share:**

```
var facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
facebookSheet.setInitialText("Share on Facebook")
self.present(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I see snapchat API is also poor. 
Can we actually do share to snapchat?

Answer (score 2):

It seems Snapchat does not allow that, they have their API private for security reasons. Their other reason is:

> It takes time and a lot of resources to build an open and trustworthy
>   third-party application ecosystem. That’s why we haven’t provided a 
>   public API to developers and why we prohibit access to the private API we > use to provide our service. Don’t get us wrong - we’re excited by the
>   interest in developing for the Snapchat platform - but we’re going to take
>   our time to get it right.

Check the link for more information.

https://www.snap.com/en-US/news/post/third-party-applications-and-the-snapchat-api/

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can share image , video, link, sticker in snapchat. Please see the link below for details tutorial..

[Snapchat Creative Kit iOS (Swift) - Image, Video, Sticker Sharing](https://mahmudul-razib.medium.com/snapchat-creative-kit-ios-swift-image-video-sticker-sharing-8ec8ed7e5efd)